# Inserir pontos num mapa com um array que passa na base de dados

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

Estou a criar um site em que preciso de uma mapa, e os utilizadores preenchem formulários com a latitude e a longitude para criar um ponto nesse mesmo mapa.
Tudo é guardado na base de dados mas eu precisava que o nome do ponto, a latitude e a longitude passassem antes num array. Ou seja, dados guardados numa base de dados mas sempre a rodar no array.
O meu código é o seguinte:

```
<html>
<?php include("header.php");?>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Google Maps </title>
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDTXwZGf67oO-63Ci_OfR7CzB7Wm003Gow&sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">

<h1><b>Roteiro Definido</b></h1>
<hr/>
<div style="float: left;">
<h2><b>Indicações</b></h2>
  <dl>
    <dt><b>Nome do Local</b></dt>
    <dd>-------------</dd>

    <dt><b>Tipo de Local</b></dt>
    <dd>-------------</dd>

    <dt><b>Moradado Local</b></dt>
    <dd>---------------</dd>

    <dt><b>Código Postal e Localidade</b></dt>
    <dd>--------------------------</dd>
  </dl></div>



    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; float: right;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var locations = [

          ['Parque estacionamento', 41.69114219999999, -8.828242600000067, 3],
          ['Praia do Norte', 41.696997, -8.850979000000052, 2],
          ['Navio Gil Eanes', 41.69009, -8.830255999999963, 1]
        ];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.694808, -8.830981),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
 </div>
<?php include("footer.php");?>
```

Comment: Você fez o `ajax` para retornar esses dados ?

Comment: Deves usar ajax para isso Melissa

Comment: @DiegoSouza Boa tarde, não, vou deixar o código inteiro para ver, vou editar a pergunta

Comment: @Miguel abe indicar-me como o fazer? Nunca usei ajax

Comment: Eu vou tentar ajudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que criar uma função ajax que faça a consulta na base de dados.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/localizacoes.php', true);

request.onload = function(){
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    var data = request.responseText;

    criarMapa(data);
  } 
  else{
    console.log('Deu erro!');
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  console.log('Deu erro!');
};

request.send();

function criarMapa(locations){

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.694808, -8.830981),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

Tem que criar uma página **PHP** para você selecionar e enviar esses dados.

Eu dei o nome de `localizacoes.php` no parâmetro do método `open()`. Mas você pode escolher outro nome para sua página.

Daí você apenas faz a consulta e retorna o `array`. Mas os dados estão dentro de outro `array`.

```
$query   = "SELECT nome, latitude, longitude FROM pontos";
$execute = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$result  = mysqli_fetch_array($execute);

$arrMaps [];

foreach($result as $key => $item){
    $arrMaps($arrMaps, [$item->nome, $item->latitude, $item->longitude, $key]);
}

return $arrMaps;
```

É apenas uma ideia, pode ser que algo dê errado.

Comment: vou testar, muito obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer assim do lado cliente, adicionar dinamicamente uma zona ao teu mapa, por default já lá tens uma zona no input pronta a testar, não longe das localizações que já lá tens (PS: Sempre bom ver alguém de Portugal aqui, bem-vinda):

```js
var locations = [
      ['Parque estacionamento', 41.69114219999999, -8.828242600000067],
      ['Praia do Norte', 41.696997, -8.850979000000052],
      ['Navio Gil Eanes', 41.69009, -8.830255999999963]
    ];

function init_map(locations) {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.611751, -8.785640),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
  }

init_map(locations);

$('#add').on('click', function() {
  var zona = $('#zona').val();
  var newCoords = $('#coords').val().split(',');
  newCoords.unshift(zona);
  locations.push(newCoords);
  init_map(locations);
  // aqui colocas o teu ajax e envias para o servidor as novas coordenadas e zona: newCoords
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

Nome da Zona<input type="text" id="zona">
<br>
Coord<input id="coords" placeholder="41.682451, -8.794165" value="41.682451, -8.794165" type="text" id="coords">
<button id="add">Add<button>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; float: right;"></div>
```

Comment: mas como faço para depois ir buscar à base de dados? é que neste caso o array vai rodar com os valores que o utilizador colocar, e assim sendo vai tudo para um BD

Comment: Ha já percebi queres que outros utilizadores também vejam o que um insere @MelissaSousa?

Comment: sim, se me conseguir ajudar

Comment: Isso é um pedido ajax dentro de um setInterval() .. Eu agora não tenho tempo de demonstrar talvez este fim de semana a consiga ajudar. Mas basicamente é um pedido ajax de 1sec em 1sec (por exemplo), para "perguntar" ao servidor se há localizações novas, caso haja, o servidor envia-as em resposta a esse pedido, e depois aí sim, entra a parte que fiz no click, que há de estar no sucesso da função ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get aqui está um exemplo @MelissaSousa